# How to decrease thread pool size value using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: multithreading

I set CorePoolSize to 10 and MaximumPoolSize to Integer.MAX_VALUE .

now i increased CorePoolSize to 15 and  getPoolSize() showed 15 threads.

After this i decreased CorePoolSize to again 10 , this time getPoolSize() is showing 15. And 15 threads are running.

I only want number of threads in threadpool as CorePoolSize and i don't want to change MaximumPoolSize value. I also don't want to fix CorePoolSize.

How this can be possible?

Answer (score 0):

The docs for `setCorePoolSize` state:

> If the new value is smaller than the current value, excess existing threads will be terminated when they next become idle.

Does your thread pool always have a lot of work to do? If you make it go idle, do you find the threads die at that point? You may want to call `setKeepAlive` to set a very short keep-alive time (potentially 0), at least temporarily.

I suspect that while there are still more tasks to process, it *will* keep existing threads alive - which makes sense, given that you've basically said you're comfortable with there being "10 or more" threads. If you've got more than 10 tasks to be processed, why wouldn't it keep processing them?